# in Angular Entering Decimal Number in german format "having comma" is not work well

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization

I am trying to localize the data entry Module (written in angular) based on the user PC (example in case the PC language setting is German  ) so the module should accept the "," as a decimal separator instead of "." ,
So I have used the Angular localization files (e.g.: angular-locale_de-de.js )  However I have an issue when insert the decimal number using the comma as the following : 
in German PC settings,  when the users insert the decimal number at this format "5,4" at the input Text Box, the display at the Label to this value shows Empty  instead of 5,40
the Label at the code as the following : `<label>{{mynumber | number:2}}</label>`

but when the user insert : "5.4" the label show "5,40" 
for simplicity I am using the code below

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script LANGUAGE=javascript src="angular.js"></script>
       <script LANGUAGE=javascript src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
      </script>
</head>
<body ng-app  >
<input  type=number id="txt" ng-model="mynumber" >
<label>{{mynumber| number : 2}}</label>
</body>
</html>
```

And that also applied when using the filter below at the controller : 
`$filter('number')(mynumber, 2)`
can you please help on how correctly format the number when insert number using comma separator (like above should be 5,40 **instead of empty**) ?
Please note : this problem is exist even using  "angular-locale_de-de.js"

Also can you please advice on how can I load the right angular localization file (e.g.: angular-locale_de-de.js depending of the **User Language  PC settings** )?
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but I am having troubles understanding what you are asking. This is partly due to your use of the English language (i.e. could you please edit your question and improve the language? I am also a non native speaker, so I know it is hard), but also due to missing error messages. Do you get any errors? Or what is the output you get and how does it differ from what you expect or want to achieve?

Comment: Works fine here, in a French Chrome browser, which also accepts commas in numbers entered in input fields of type number: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4K1n2Rp8pE4ctm3y7cB?p=preview. Angular is irrelevant here, AFAIK. What matters is the browser. All the number filter does is taking a number in argument, provided by the browser input field, and format it.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet,I am using IE,  however it is the same behaviour just please try to change type="text" and then re-execute the  Plnkr again and then try to  write "5.3"  chrome then  will show you "5,30" but when you write "5,3" using "," instead of "." then chrome also will show you empty same behaviour as IE

Comment: What's the point? That obviously won't work, since the number filter expects a number, and not a string.

Comment: Hi JBNized , German users use  "," to for the decimal number  instead of dot ( based on their language setting), but at this situation the user should write "." instead of comma to display the right value , I think logically Angular should considers number seperated by "," as number based on the PC user setting .so what is the best way to let the user use "," for their input and angular consider it as a number

Comment: The best way is to use an input of type number to let users input a number. Not an input of type text. With an input of type number, on a German browser, German people will be able to enter numbers with commas.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, this example in IE11 is not working properly. I have entered in this one 5,5 and I see nothing. I have entered 5.5 and I see 5,5.
http://plnkr.co/edit/x4K1n2Rp8pE4ctm3y7cB?p=preview
Expected behavior is that I shall put 5,5 into it and I shall see 5,5 in IE too.

Answer (score 2):

There is angular directive (I am the author) which allow only numbers, minus sign and selected separator ',' or ','. Link: https://github.com/uhlryk/angular-dynamic-number

You can config number of integer digits, number of fraction digits, choose separator, or allow positive, negative or both numbers. It block other chars in input view value, but dynamically convert model value. This module also has filter to modify ngBind to show for example comma separator instead of dot.

After Installation (bower, npm or manualy) add module to your application as dependency, and then:

```
<input  type="text" id="txt" ng-model="mynumber" awnum num-sep="," num-fract="2">
<label>{{mynumber| awnum : 2 : ',' : 'round' : 'true'}}</label>
```

I build this module to process forms with prices in Poland.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to make it work with angular 1.2.28 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert english number format into german number format. You can use following code in typescript -

```
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79"
```

You can find more number formats and details here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat